ag grid row height on column select/unselect
I am using server side row model ag grid. I have two columns in grid for which autoheight and wraptext is set to true. First time when page is loaded and on pagination as well row height is set based on content. but when I  select/ unselect column from column tool panel then row height is not getting changed automatically. I am deselecting the column due to which row height is very high . On deselecting I want row height should be less as content is not very much for another columns. but row height remain same on selecting/unselecting column in column tool panel
Is there any way so that row height changed automatically on select/unselect column.
